# How can I invoke several clients' async methods and aggregate the results into one task generically?

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, task, .net-4.5

The following code is intended to reduce redundant code by allowing you to generically invoke the same selector on a set of "getters" (data retrieval clients) and have all of the results combined. The final result set is awaitable, allowing the system to not block while waiting for all of the selectors to complete.

```
public async Task<T> GetBulkAsync<T>(Func<IGetter, Task<T>> selector) where T : IEnumerable<T>
{
    Task<T>[] tasks = new Task<T>[this.getters.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.getters.Count; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = selector(this.getters[i]);
    }

    T[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    return results.SelectMany<T, T>(r => r);
}
```

However, a problem comes up in my design here. There is one case where I simply want to use a selector that retrieves a single `IData` and then there's times where a selector will retrieve an `IEnumerable<IData>` or maybe a `List<IData>` or something entirely different.

I have thought about using reflection to handle special cases with generic collections, but that's messy and requires additional work for every type of collection I want to handle.

The main reason I care about `IEnumerable<IData>` (or really, `IEnumerable<T>`) is because I want to use Linq's SelectMany in order to flatten out all of the results in the big result set. If each selector is coming back with an `IEnumerable<T>`, it needs to be reduced into one `IEnumerable<T>`, not an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`.

Is there a good approach to solving this issue other than writing several different generic methods with constraints on collection types and without using reflection?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what the problem is with the code as presented. It is already retrieving an array of `T : IE<T>` and combining them with `SelectMany`. What exactly do you want this method to do that it is not already doing? Also, what are the semantics of `IE<T>` for `T`: is it a "Children" list or a "SelfAndChildren" list? (BTW, you will find some limitations in what you can do in advanced code like this just because `Task<T>` is not variant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of relying on *one* type parameter, use two and provide a transformation/projection function at the end, like so:

```
public async Task<TResult> GetBulkAsync<T, TResult>(
    Func<IGetter, Task<T>> selector,
    Func<IEnumerable<T>, TResult> aggregateSelector) 
        where T : IEnumerable<T>
{
    Task<T>[] tasks = new Task<T>[this.getters.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.getters.Count; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = selector(this.getters[i]);
    }

    T[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    return results.Select<T, TResult>(aggregateSelector);
}
```

The `aggregateSelector` would basically transform each `IEnumerable<T>` into a new `TResult` instance and you'd return an `IEnumerable<TResult>`.

However, I recommend against this, as you're relying on composition to occur *in* the function, when it really doesn't have to.

Instead, I think you should return a sequence of sequences, like so:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>> GetBulkAsync<T>(
    Func<IGetter, Task<T>> selector) 
        where T : IEnumerable<T>
{
    Task<T>[] tasks = new Task<T>[this.getters.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.getters.Count; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = selector(this.getters[i]);
    }

    T[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    return results.Select(t => t.Result):
}
```

This way, you can compose the results any way you want without having to change this method.

Comment: Wouldn't this return a sequence of sequences of sequences? Since T is constrained against `IEnumerable<T>`, then you have `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` for the return type. It'd make an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>>` right? My goal is basically to have numerous selector methods which can each return either one result, a set of results, or a set of sets of sets... etc. But in the end, I want one flat sequence of results.

Comment: I kept hacking at it and came to this conclusion essentially. Thanks :)